# gcc generates binary of size 0 with -Os

Tags: c, gcc, arm, freertos

I have a simple FreeRTOS application that just toggles an LED in the main loop.
When I compile it with `-Os`, the resulting binary has size 0. Without `-Os` everything works as expected. What is happening here?

My `CFLAGS` are:

```
CPUFLAG = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4
FPUFLAG = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
WFLAG   = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes

CFLAGS  += -std=gnu99 $(WFLAG) $(CPUFLAG) $(FPUFLAG) -mlittle-endian -mthumb -nostartfiles
CFLAGS  += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-builtin
LDFLAGS += -nostdlib --gc-sections -static
```

main is basically TI's blinky demo:

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t ui32Loop;

    //
    // Enable the GPIO port that is used for the on-board LED.
    //
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R = SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOF;

    //
    // Do a dummy read to insert a few cycles after enabling the peripheral.
    //
    ui32Loop = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;

    //
    // Enable the GPIO pin for the LED (PF3).  Set the direction as output, and
    // enable the GPIO pin for digital function.
    //
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x08;
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x08;

    //
    // Loop forever.
    //
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Turn on the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x08;

        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }

        //
        // Turn off the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~(0x08);

        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With `-Os` this generates

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      0       0       0       0       0 image.elf
```

otherwise

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2012       4     728    2744     ab8 image.elf
```

**edit**: [differences in .map files](http://www.mergely.com/soOsNwHR)

Comment: How are `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` and friends declared?

Comment: `#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R       (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x400253FC))`

Comment: Is the `image.elf` file actually empty, or does it just have a size of 0 as reported by the `size` command? `ls -l image.elf`

Comment: `ls -sh image.*` gives `0 image.bin*  4,0K image.elf*`

Comment: Did you look at a map file?  I am pretty sure it would give an answer.  It could be section naming for instance.

Comment: There is no map file - here is the entire [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/LrnMKd3V)

Comment: Alter the value `LDFLAGS` to add a `-Map project.map` and it will generate a map file.

Comment: Ok, there are [clear differences](http://www.mergely.com/soOsNwHR/) but I don't know how to interpret them. (left is with `-Os`, right is without)

Answer (score 4):

Since you specified `-nostartfiles`, the standard startup and its entrypoint is not used, so there is no reference to your `main` function, and `--gc-sections` discards the whole section as unused.

To fix, try to either name your function `start` or add `-e _main` to the `ld` flags.

Comment: Well the actual startup code would be in the reset interrupt - should I export that and tell the linker about it?

Comment: This makes sense, but it would seem to apply for either *-Os* or the default optimizer unless he has **LTO** (link time optimization) in the tool chain.  Anyways, it is good advice to specify an entry point.